# Ubuntu 16.04 and fallback mode settings misunderstanding

Tags: compiz, 16.04, gnome-classic

I've updated my 14.04 to 16.04. As a big unity-hater, I immediately reinstalled gnome-flashback. But it turned out I cannot configure it with ccsm anymore (as a simple example, trying to bind 'show desktop' onto right bottom corner of the screen would give no effect).

Now I'm stuck in an odd situation, where I've set a "Radiance" theme in unity-control-center, which affected my compiz panels (like taskbar), they became white. But window headers still stay black, seems like they are no longer affected by the 'theme' menu item.

Also I use multiple keyboard layouts. To switch them I use alt-Lshift. In unity this still works, but in fallback mode I have to rebind the combination - pressing the same alt-Lshift on my keyboard, the 'text entry' application records it as 'alt+Next Group'. Which is really strange.

Based on everything I said, here're 3 questions:

1) How to get rid off Lshift being threatened as 'Next Group' in fallback mode?
2) Which application shall be used to set up fallback mode? unity's or compiz's or something else?
3) More specific, how can I make window headers be the same color as my main panels?